# Silent Hill 4: The room crashes after I enter first portal back to the apartment. I am using Widescreen fix

Tags: technical-issues, silent-hill-series, silent-hill-4

My *Silent Hill 4: The Room* crashes after I enter the first portal back to the apartment. I am using the "Widescreen fix." When I met Cynthia, she went to the restroom, and then I killed the 2 dogs. When I entered the restrooms, there is that "portal - giant hole" but when I decided to go back to apartment via that hole my game crashes every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out it only crashes when you want to enter the restrooms when you didn't explore the whole area to the end of train station. In my opinion it is probably a bug or "unhandled exception" in the code of the game.